# Something gone crazy with my jquery code

Tags: jquery, html

I'm selecting a select element and making the value to be written to a hidden element.

But don't know why my jquery code is not working. Not getting any error on the console also.

```
$('#subject').change(function() {
   $("#sub_id").val($(this).val());
})

<select id="subject">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">English</option>
    <option value="2">Science</option>
    <option value="3">Math</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" class="sub_id" name="subjectId" />
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hidden field has class defined, but you had used it as id selector.

You need to use as this

```
$('#subject').change(function() {
   $(".sub_id").val($(this).val());
})
```

Comment: Opps... on the run i did really missed it.

Answer (score 0):

Change `#` to `.` `#` is id selector and `.` is class selector.

```
$('#subject').change(function() {
   $(".sub_id").val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: @SnehanjaliSahoo Any time :)

Answer (score 0):

You have used Id selector instead of class for the hidden field.

If your Element is availble prior to dom load the use

```
$('#subject').change(function() {
   $(".sub_id").val($(this).val());
});
```

if you are adding this element later to the page.

```
$("#subject").on('change',  (function() {
   $(".sub_id").val($(this).val());
});
```